# Display a legend by iterating through an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the outcome I am looking for

[image]

At the moment, I hardcode it like this:

```
<a href='#' id="educational"><span style='background-color: #65dc1e'></span><b>Educational Support</b></a><br>
<a href='#' id="economic"><span style='background-color: #17f3d1'></span><b>Economic Sufficiency</b></a><br>
<a href='#' id="service"><span style='background-color: #e55e5e'></span><b>International Service</b></a><br>
<a href='#' id="environmental"><span style='background-color: #1743f3'></span><b>Environmental Stewardship</b></a><br>
<a href='#' id="health"><span style='background-color: #ba55d3'></span><b>Health & Wellness</b></a><br>
<a href='#' id="justice"><span style='background-color: #FFFF00'></span><b>Social Justice</b></a><br>
```

But I want to dynamically have two arrays of Mission areas and color to populate the legend:

```
var mission = ["Economic Sufficiency", "Educational Support", "Environmental Stewardship", "Health and Wellness", "International Service", "Social Justice"]
var colorcode = ['#17f3d1','#65dc1e', '#1743f3', '#ba55d3', '#e55e5e', '#FFFF00']
```

The order in both arrays is sorted and configured so that each color corresponds to the correct mission area. My current code is this:

```
var select = '';
select += '<a href="#" ' + 'id='+'"all"><span style="background-color: black"></span><b>All Mission Areas</b></a>' + "<br>";
for (var i=1;i<=Missionarea.length;i++){
    var color = colorcode[i]
    var mission = Missionarea[i]
    select += '<a href="#" ' + 'id='+'"mission.valueOf()"><span style="background-color: color"></span><b>mission.toString()</b></a>' + "<br>";
}
$('#legend').html(select);
```

[image]

I tried multiple ways but couldn't get the result I wanted; which is:

- Assign the Mission area to the id tag & as an option in the legend
- Assign the matching color

If you have any advice on how to do this, it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: You have more color code than missions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I chose the wrong array in my code. Post was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *select* string is not properly formatted. You also have mismatch in the variable name used in your code. You can format the *htmlString* with string concatenation like:

```
select += '<a href="#" id="'+mission.valueOf()+'"><span style="background-color:'+color+'"><b>'+mission.toString()+'</b></span></a>' + "<br>";
```

***Working Code Example:***

```js
var Missionarea = ["Business", "Government Agency", "Higher Education Institution", "K-12", "Nonprofit"]
var colorcode = ['#17f3d1','#65dc1e', '#1743f3', '#ba55d3', '#e55e5e', '#FFFF00']

var select = '';
select += '<a href="#" ' + 'id='+'"all"><span style="background-color: black"></span><b>All Mission Areas</b></a>' + "<br>";
for (var i=0;i<Missionarea.length;i++){
    var color = colorcode[i]
    var mission = Missionarea[i]
    select += '<a href="#" id="'+mission.valueOf()+'"><span style="background-color:'+color+'"><b>'+mission.toString()+'</b></span></a>' + "<br>";
}
$('#legend').html(select)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="legend"></div>
```

Though I prefer with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allowed embedded expressions like:

```
select += `<a href="#" id="${mission.valueOf()}"><span style="background-color: ${color}"><b>${mission.toString()}</b></span></a><br>`;
```

***Working Code Example:***

```js
var Missionarea = ["Business", "Government Agency", "Higher Education Institution", "K-12", "Nonprofit"]
var colorcode = ['#17f3d1','#65dc1e', '#1743f3', '#ba55d3', '#e55e5e', '#FFFF00']

var select = '';
select += '<a href="#" ' + 'id='+'"all"><span style="background-color: black"></span><b>All Mission Areas</b></a>' + "<br>";
for (var i=0;i<Missionarea.length;i++){
    var color = colorcode[i]
    var mission = Missionarea[i]
    select += `<a href="#" id="${mission.valueOf()}"><span style="background-color: ${color}"><b>${mission.toString()}</b></span></a><br>`;
}
$('#legend').html(select)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="legend"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var missionDom = document.querySelectAll('a');

missionDom.forEach(function(val, idx ){
    val.children[0].styles.background-color = colorCode[idx];
    val.children[1].textContent = mission[idx];

document.querySelector('#legend').appendChild(val);
});
```